# SQL Alchemy other Column not selecting in Table

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

If i want to search for a specific user with the Username the API returns:

`GET /users/test HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity`

[image]

And if I put an id there it returns the correct id with the correct user. Does smn know the fix

main.py

```
@app.get("/user/{username}")
async def get_user_username(username: str):
    return conn.execute(users.select().where(users.c.username == username)).fetchall()
```

models/users.py

```
users = Table(
    'users',meta,
    Column('id',Integer,primary_key=True),
    Column('username',String),
    Column('password',String)
)
```

schemas/users.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class User(BaseModel):
    id:int
    username:str
    password:str
```

Comment: Do you have any other routes in your app on the same URL, that might expect an integer?

Comment: Yeah i had another route where u can find the user by ID Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had another route where the user id was asked.